# how to UPPER subquery?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Oracle SQL Developer:

I need to compare upcase subquery output result with a string,  but the code below does not work - *missing expression*

> SELECT UPPER(SELECT 'abcd' FROM DUAL) FROM DUAL

but at the same time I can execute this

> SELECT UPPER('abcd') FROM DUAL

Please advise how to avoid the problem and use subquery within UPPER.

Comment: You might want to tell us what the real problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try rephrasing your query to allow aliasing the value inside the subquery.

```
SELECT
    UPPER(t.val) AS val
FROM (SELECT 'abcd' AS val FROM DUAL) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your question but for UPPER a subquery it is like this :

```html
SELECT (SELECT UPPER('abcd') FROM DUAL) FROM DUAL
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: The question was how to upper subquery. You just transformed this excluding subquery from upper.

Comment: My bad ! Sorry, seeing his example, I thought he wanted to do an upper inside the sub-query.